# Pygame ValueError: invalid rectstyle object

Tags: python, pygame

I downloaded a pygame example from [here](https://github.com/eventia/rabbitone) called rabbitone, and followed the corresponding [youtube video](https://youtu.be/TU4qDHBBHes).

So I have studied the code and tried it:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()


width, height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

player = pygame.image.load("resources/images/dude.png")


while True:
    screen.fill(0,0,0)
    pygame.display.flip()
    screen.blit(player, (100,100))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
```

In the video tutorial I'm following, the code works. Why do I get this error?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 2, in
>
> ValueError: invalid rectstyle object

Comment: Could you link to the source you are copying from?

Comment: copying from : https://github.com/eventia/rabbitone and  youtube video :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TU4qDHBBHes

Comment: Have you cloned the repo and are trying to run it locally?

Comment: player = pygame.image.load("/Users/eomtae/Desktop/Python tutorial 1/rabbitone-master/resources/images/dude.png")  This is my code.. Is it right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're passing three separate integers to the [`pygame.Surface.fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) method, but you have to pass a color tuple (or list or [`pygame.Color`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html) object) as the first argument : `screen.fill((0, 0, 0))`.

You also need to blit the player between the `fill` and the `flip` call, otherwise you'll only see a black screen.

---

Unrelated to the problem, but you should usually [`convert`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) your surfaces to improve the performance and add a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) to limit the frame rate.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()

width, height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
# Add a clock to limit the frame rate.
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Convert the image to improve the performance (convert or convert_alpha).
player = pygame.image.load("resources/images/dude.png").convert_alpha()

running = True
while running:
    # Handle events.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Insert the game logic here.

    # Then draw everything, flip the display and call clock tick.
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(player, (100, 100))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)  # Limit the frame rate to 60 FPS.

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but it was in a different situation.
I put `surface.fill(0,0,0)`
To fix this, I put `surface.fill((0,0,0))`
With a pair of extra brackets aroud the colour