# why does python think of my screen.fill function is a rect function

Tags: python, pygame, screen, rect

so, i was coding in python in the way i normally do, i was using pygame, but the python shell thinks that i am saying that i want to define a `rect`, eventhough i was using the `screen.fill` function, which in my case is the `win.fill` function, anyways, here is my code (the broken part)

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((650, 650))
x = random.randint(100, 600)
y = random.randint(100, 400)
win.fill(255, 255, 255)
```

so, it must have worked properly and make the screen white, but instead, it says this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pert/PycharmProjects/crocodile game/game.py", line 8, in <module>
    win.fill(255, 255, 255)
ValueError: invalid rectstyle object
```

can anybody tell me how to tell python this is NOT a rect

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a duplicate of [Pygame ValueError: invalid rectstyle object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51301032/pygame-valueerror-invalid-rectstyle-object) ?

Here's the answer from the above post:

"You're passing three separate integers to the pygame.Surface.fill method, but you have to pass a color tuple (or list or pygame.Color object) as the first argument : screen.fill((0, 0, 0)).

You also need to blit the player between the fill and the flip call, otherwise you'll only see a black screen."

Comment: in your case you would have to do win.fill((255, 255, 255))

Comment: i have blitted the player in later code, just that i have not noted it here

Comment: Yes but did you pass a tuple to the win.fill function? Like: win.fill((255,255,255)) and not win.fill(255,255,255)?